# Sidebar Animation using FramerMotion with Chakra UI not working when state is switched to React Context

Tags: javascript, reactjs, animation, framer-motion, chakra-ui

I'm trying to create a Sliding Sidebar animation in react with `framer-motion` using the `Grid` component of `@chakra-ui/react`. The animation is working when the state is inside the same component with the animated component.

However, I want to migrate the state to a ContextProvider so that I can toggle the sidebar from anywhere inside the Layout. As soon as I moved the state to Context, the animation is not working anymore. I kind of know the problem is the Context re-rendering it's child. However I don't have any idea how to make the animation works with ContextProvider. Please help me.

In case you want the complete working example, [CodesandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-pine-31fjyh?file=/src/NotWorkingWithContext.tsx)

---

#### Working Simple Example (As described from the framer-motion docs)

```js
import { Grid, GridItem, Button } from '@chakra-ui/react'
import { motion, useCycle } from 'framer-motion'

const MotionGrid = motion(Grid)

export function DashboardLayout() {
  const [sidebarState, toggleSidebar] = useCycle('expand', 'collapse')
  const variants = {
    expand: { gridTemplateColumns: '230px 1fr' },
    collapse: { gridTemplateColumns: '55px 1fr' },
  }
  return (
    <MotionGrid
      animate={sidebarState}
      variants={variants}
      gridTemplateRows="80px 1fr"
    >
      <GridItem rowSpan={1} colSpan={2}>
        <Button onClick={() => toggleSidebar()}>ToggleSidebar</Button>
      </GridItem>
      <GridItem>Navbar Here</GridItem>
      <GridItem>Main Content Here</GridItem>
    </MotionGird>
  )
}
```

---

#### Not Working Example when switched to ContextProvider

```js
import * as React from 'react'
import { Grid, GridItem, Button } from '@chakra-ui/react'
import { motion, useCycle } from 'framer-motion'

const SidebarContext = React.useContext({
  sidebarState: 'expand',
  toggleSidebar: () => {},
})
function useSidebar() {
  return React.useContext(SidebarContext)
}
function SidebarProvider({ children }) {
  const [sidebarState, toggleSidebar] = useCycle('expand', 'collapse')
  return (
    <SidebarContext.Provider value={{ sidebarState, toggleSidebar }}>
      {children}
    </SidebarContext.Provider>
  )
}

export function DashboardLayout() {
  const MotionGrid = motion(Grid)
  const { sidebarState, toggleSidebar } = useSidebar()
  const variants = {
    expand: { gridTemplateColumns: '230px 1fr' },
    collapse: { gridTemplateColumns: '55px 1fr' },
  }
  return (
    <MotionGrid
      animate={sidebarState}
      variants={variants}
      gridTemplateRows="80px 1fr"
    >
      <GridItem rowSpan={1} colSpan={2}>
        <Button onClick={() => toggleSidebar()}>ToggleSidebar</Button>
      </GridItem>
      <GridItem>Navbar Here</GridItem>
      <GridItem>Main Content Here</GridItem>
    </MotionGird>
  )
}

// Inside App.js
export default function App() {
  return (
    <SidebarProvider>
      <DashboardLayout></DashboardLayout>
    </SidebarProvider>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer. It is such a common mistake that I make. I was initializing the `MotionGrid` component inside the Layout component, which will trigger re-render when the state is changed and re-create the new `MotionGrid` component. Just by re-locating the `MotionGrid` initializing as a separate component fixed the problem.

---

##### Before

```js
export function DashboardLayout() {
  const MotionGrid = motion(Grid)
  ...
}
```

---

##### After

```js
const MotionGrid = motion(Grid)

export function DashboardLayout() {
  return (
    <MotionGrid>
    ...
  )
}
```